# ended event videojs not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I would like to trigger a simple event when my video is finished. I've placed this directly bellow my video tag.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        var myPlayer = videojs("session_video");
          videojs("session_video").ready(function(){
          this.addEvent("ended", function(){ 
            alert('Here I am');
          });
        });       
     </script>
```

However I get: TypeError: this.addEvent is not a function and I can't find why.

You can see it live here: 78.47.121.50 (stackoverflow won't allow to make that a link) 
enter code 01-01-01-2012 to bring up the video.

Any insight is much apricaited!

Kind regards,
Jason.

Comment: It could be a `this` problem, as the `ready` method appears to be asynchronous.  What do you think `this` is referring to? On what object are you expecting the `addEvent` method to be present?

Comment: @Sushil It's an video player which combines html, js and flash to create an universal player. (see: http://videojs.com)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

"addEvent" and "removeEvent" were replaced by "on" and "off"

try:

```
this.on("ended", function(){
```

Comment: Hi Lyn, this did the trick! Many thanks for that :)
Could you tell me where you found this info? I couldn't find it in the docs.

Comment: i noticed it as the most recent commit comment in the github repo for the project. just random luck really.

Comment: Well, thanks for sharing! Stupid the don't include it in the docs... 
I'm now trying to include a plugin for videojs but it's still using addEvent and _V_ 

Would you know if I could just replace that for on/off & videojs?

Answer (score 6):

For those who still have problems with ended events in some browsers you can resort to this fix:

```
    player.ready(function() {
            var myPlayer = this;

            playerInstance.on("timeupdate", function(event) { //chrome fix
                if (event.currentTarget.currentTime == event.currentTarget.duration) {
                    console.log('video ended');
                }
            });
    });
```

Comment: My ended event is not firing when using the Chrome browser.  I have tried this fix, but it does not seem to work. I am thinking it might need to be included within the:
videojs("video2").ready(function(){
Would that be more appropriate?  
Can't understand why it works on other browsers but not Chrome...

Comment: This helped me out with the weird chrome bug sometimes not triggering ended. Thanks!

Comment: @CalebO'Leary, I am getting error: Cannot find name 'playerInstance'. after adding the above code. any help?

Answer (score 5):

The **ended** event will not fire if end user intentionally seek the video to end keeping video as paused. I was able to get it work as:

```js
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var player = videojs('my_video', {}, function() {});
      player.ready(function(){
        var duration_time =  Math.floor(this.duration());
        this.on('timeupdate', function() {
          var current_time =  Math.floor(this.currentTime());
          if ( current_time > 0 && ( current_time == duration_time ) ){
            $('#continue_button').removeAttr("disabled");
          }
        });
      });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

**2020 Updated answer:**

```
let player = videojs('video-player-id');

player.on('ended', function() {
  this.dispose();
});
```

I think it's good to call dispose More on why over [here](https://docs.videojs.com/player#dispose)

Answer (score 1):

On Stackoverflow i find  one part of solution the otherpart find it from Lyn Headley top answer.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //rename subtitle button
    videojs.addLanguage('de', {
        "captions off": "Untertitel aus",
    });

    videojs(document.querySelector('video') /* or selector string */, {
        techOrder: ['html5', 'flash'],
        controls: true,
        autoplay: false,
        preload: 'false',
        language: 'de',
        flash: {
            swf: 'video-js.swf'
        }
    }, function(){
        // Player (this) is initialized and ready.
        this.on('ended', function(){
            alert('ended');
        });
        this.on('firstplay', function(){
            alert('firstplay');
        });
    });
</script>
```

this will alert you on the end of video.
place it under the code of your video
and it should works.

Comment: I'm using this solution with Vue3's composition API where I initialise the player with the events that I want to detect during `onMounted`.