# Switching sources after html5 video has ended

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming, html5-video

I know this should be straight forward if I just use the onended event, like this:

```
  <video src="video.ogv" id="myVideo">
  </video>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
    function myHandler(e) {
        // What you want to do after the event
    }
</script>
```

however, the *ended* event is firing the evn after I switch tracks. I am using the [videojs](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/stable/docs/api/vjs.Player.md#ended-event) player.

**In this particular case, I'm looking play Clip B, and the moment it finishes, switch to Clip C.**

Here is what my code looks like:

```
// clipA is currently playing......
// User hits a button which calls switchVideo();

// video = videojs('video-player');
var switchVideo = function (clipB, clipC) {
    video.src(clipB);
    video.play();

    // When clipB has ended...
    video.ended(function () {
        console.log("clipB ended");
        video.src(clipC);
        video.play();
    })
};
```

The moment I call this function, I can see that it jumps to clipB for a moment, then the onended event is fired, and then the video feed jumps to clipC. **How can I ignore the first onended event for clipA, and instead only listen for clipB?**

**UPDATE:** Here is what the final correct answer looks like:

```
   // video = videojs('video-player');
    var switchVideo = function (clipB, clipC) {
        video.src(clipB);
        video.play();

        // When clipB has ended...
        video.one('ended', function () {
            console.log("clibB ended");
            video.src(clipC);
            video.play();
        })
    };
```

**UPDATE 2:** I discovered that the above code will only work once. (It is called 'one' afterall. In my particular case, I needed to be able to do this several times.

I made one small change, and that was to use *video.on('ended', myfunction)* instead of *video.one('ended', myFunction)*. Now I can call it as many times as needed.

I came to this conclusion after reading [this Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573974/ended-event-videojs-not-working) response.

> "addEvent" and "removeEvent" were replaced by "on" and "off" [per the videojs API.](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/api/vjs.Player.md#on-first-second-third-) - @Lyn Headley

**Final solution:**

```
       // video = videojs('video-player');
        var switchVideo = function (clipB, clipC) {
            video.src(clipB);
            video.play();

            // When clipB has ended...
            video.on('ended', function () {
                console.log("clibB ended");
                video.src(clipC);
                video.play();
            })
        };
```

Comment: Have you tried `video.one('ended', function () {whatever})`? This will only run the function once the video has ended, and only once, preventing the callbacks from stacking up.

Comment: @keizom I don't see any jQuery here.

Comment: Have you tried removeEventListener(), switch to other video, the re-attach the event handler?

Comment: @DavidDomain Asker is using a library _videojs_, which has events of its own. That is where `video.ended` is coming from. [https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/stable/docs/api/vjs.Player.md#one-first-second-third-

Comment: @keizom Ok, so the `one` method comes from *video.js*, got it.

Comment: I don't have any issues with using jQuery here -- if it works for this instance, I'd be glad to add it to the project.

Good point about removeEventLister, @m69. I'll try that now.

Comment: @keizom let me try video.one right now as well. Will report back in a moment.

Comment: clip.one worked like a charm, thank you! I was misunderstanding how that function behaved at first. I thought it was for only the FIRST clip the player ever uses -- I didn't realize that I can use this over-and-over when switching clips.

@keizom mind writing this an an answer so that I can give you credit?

Comment: Wrote my solution into an answer. Cheers @DaveVoyles-MSFT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For readers: asker is using a library called videojs, which envelops the native JS-<video> interface. Of which, it provides event functions: `on`, `off`, `one`.

The original code created a new event listener for every time the `switchVideo` was called, causing the `ended` callback to be called multiple times.

The solution is to use `one('ended')` instead of `ended` [equivalent to `on('ended')`]:

```
video.one('ended', function () {
    whatever;
});
```